# Checking XML file for specified rules

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xml-validation

Let's say I have the following xml file:

```
<report>
  <income>
    <amount type="type1">50</amount>
    <amount type="type2">100</amount>
  </income>
  <outcome>
    <amount type="type1">75</amount>
    <amount type="type2">10</amount>
  </outcome>
</report>
```

I want to be sure that xml file contains only above tags, type attribute is only type1 or type2, and amount is only integer. What should I use to validate xml file according to specified rules? Must I do it manually (parse xml file and check each tag for rules) or is there any method like predefining template or anything else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need an [XML Schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema)

> An XML schema is a description of a type of XML document, typically
>   expressed in terms of constraints on the structure and content of
>   documents of that type, above and beyond the basic syntactical
>   constraints imposed by XML itself. These constraints are generally
>   expressed using some combination of grammatical rules governing the
>   order of elements, Boolean predicates that the content must satisfy,
>   data types governing the content of elements and attributes, and more
>   specialized rules such as uniqueness and referential integrity
>   constraints.

There's a tutorial [here](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) to get you started.